# why is console.log output different from a return output

Tags: javascript, jsbin, bloc.io

I'm new to JavaScript so sorry for the amateur question but I feel as through the answer would help to make more sense of the course material, and assignments, in my online course. Here it is. When I write console.log like this:

```
var getKeys = function(objOne){
  for(var property in objOne){
    console.log(property);
  }
};
```

console returns:
"name"
"age"

...but if I change console.log to "return", like this:

```
var getKeys = function(objOne){
  for(var property in objOne){
    return property;
  }
};
```

output returns:
"name"

Why are the returns different?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into the console, and I receive the exact same output.

Comment: Because as soon as you `return` - you return.

Comment: Because after a `return` you’re no longer in the function, so the loop is interrupted as well.

Comment: Oh OK. That sorta makes sense. The console.log is just showing me the possible outcome of the function but if I want to return all Keys of an Object, I need to figure out how to compile each index of the loop and pass it to the return statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9), (emphasis mine)

> A `return` statement causes a function to **cease execution** and return a
>   value to the caller.

So your `for...in` loop will never reach a 2nd iteration.

Comment: So I need to pass the results of the loop into a new Array, and return that new array, in order for the function to return both keys?

Comment: @JeffreyNixon Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Because `return` exits the function. You exit the function on the first property, hence why it is only one.

> [MDN
>   `return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)
>
> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to
>   be returned to the function caller.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` and `return` are completely different things.

For the first case, you see

```
"name"
"age"
> undefined
```

because you tell the console to explicitly log the keys, but the second case, with the `return` keyword, you tell the function to terminate and return the value `"name"`, that's why you only see

```
> "name"
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log()` will print to the console your passed in arguments, where as `return` stops the execution of your function and returns whatever you tell it to.

Answer (score 0):

Once a function hits a return statement, it will stop executing; so in the first example, it loops through both. In the second, it hits that return statement and says, "Ok, I'm done."